# Convert an API KEY to string of numbers and reverse in ActionScripts3

Tags: actionscript-3

We need to convert some API KEYs to string numbers and convert that numbers to original string.

```
Sample API KEY: "ZfIgG9LliwY4cDw4Rqso0m7SEQZovI"
```

We converted it with our algorithm

```
var encode_array:Array = "ZfIgG9LliwY4cDw4Rqso0m7SEQZovI".split("");
var encode_string:String;
var count1:int = encode_array.length; var i1:int;
for (i1 = 0; i1 < count1; i1++) 
{ 

    switch(encode_array[i1]) 
   { 
    case "*": 
        encode_string += *;
        break; 
    ...
   }

Converted API KEY:"364219431799224845593594391459942853555190499729152736515819"
```

Each **2** numbers in this string are related to **1** chracter in API KEY.(Sample: "36" > "Z")

My problem is second part to reverse this (convert each 2 number to defined character), How to possible separate every **2** numbers in this string and save them in an array?
I think it possible with **Split""** or **RegExp** in ActionScripts, but i don't know how.

Comment: what exactly causes the problem?

Comment: In first part of code that work true is it possible to separate each 1 character from string, in second part i need to separate each 2 characters, i don't know second part solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a straightforward method:

```
        var s:String = '364219431799224845593594391459942853555190499729152736515819';
        for (var i:int = 0; i < s.length; i += 2) {
            var sub:String = s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i + 1);
            trace(sub);//convert 
        }
```

Comment: Codes working fine. But why a "null" will be added to first of strings ?

Comment: I used switch statement for (sub) to convert each 2 numbers to a specific character. result is true but that (null) first of final string is problem.

Comment: Final String: "nullZfIgG9LliwY4cDw4Rqso0m7SEQZovI"

Comment: it depends on what comes into your `switch` on the first call and how does it handle it.